# Change background color of subpages

Tags: css, custom-background

I have several pages, which are ordered like this:

```
Home
Projects
- Project 1
-- Project 1 Subpage 1
-- Project 1 Subpage 2
- Project 2
-- ...
```

And I want to change the background color (in this case of `.site-main {}` or any other css classes) depending on the page the user is right now.

1. Currently on Home page (this is the default layout) -> Standard background color light blue
2. I am on Page Project 1 -> background should be green.
3. I am on Project 1 Subpage 1 -> background should be green.
4. I am on Project 2 -> background red or something else

This is the standard layout right now (the lightest part should be changed):

[image]

What would be the best/easiest way to achieve this?

**Edit:**

What I did know is this:

In my page.php I added this

```
<div id="main-content" class="main-content <?php echo "roadkill-main-content"; ?>">
```

This is working fine (I'm getting another color now). 
What's missing is how to detect if the current page is child or grandchild or whatever of a page with the slug "project1" or others. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Use the existing body classes which you can grab from the source code.

Comment: Some more hints please. Any link

Comment: Link to a sub page on your site.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution could be you register a meta box for the project pages which lets you type in whatever class name you want for each page…

```
function add_project_page_metabox() {
    add_meta_box(
        'project_page_meta',    //  $id
        'Project Meta', 
                        //  $title
        'ppm_callback', //  $callback
        'page', //  $post_type  
        'side',         //  $context
        'low'           //  $priority
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_project_page_metabox' );

function ppm_callback() {
    global $post;
    $project_class = get_post_meta($post->ID,'project_class',TRUE);
    wp_nonce_field( $_POST['page_meta_noncename'],__FILE__);

    /*  some UI styling */ ?>
<style type="text/css">
#project_page_meta          {display:block;margin:0 0 12px;float:none;}
#project_page_meta label    {display:block;margin:0 1em .6em 0;}
#project_page_meta input    {margin:0 0 .25em;clear:both;float:none;max-width:97%;}
</style>
    <label>Add class name</label>
    <input class="project_class" size="35" type="text" name="project_class" value="<?php if($project_class) { echo $project_class; } ?>"/>
    <?php
}

    //  process the meta
function project_meta_save($post_id) {
    if(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) { return $post_id; }
    $accepted_fields['page'] = array(
        'project_class' 
    );
    foreach($accepted_fields['page'] as $key){
        $custom_field = $_POST[$key];
        //If no data is entered
        if      (is_null($custom_field)) { delete_post_meta($post_id, $key); }
        elseif  (isset($custom_field) && !is_null($custom_field))
                { update_post_meta($post_id,$key,$custom_field); } 
        else    { add_post_meta($post_id, $key, $custom_field, TRUE); }
    }
    return $post_id;
}
add_action('save_post', 'project_meta_save', 3, 1 );
```

…then use this in your page.php  like `class="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'project_class',TRUE); ?>"`

Answer (score 1):

Brad Dalton already gave a bit to answer this — add a body class (`<body <?php body_class('nameofyourclass'); ?>>`). Then the next step is to have a look at the classes WP adds automatically. Those are (in regard to your example):

```
Projects:               .page-parent
- Project 1:            .page-parent and .page-child
-- Project 1 Subpage 1  .page-child
```

Now take advantage of all those in your stylesheet like:

```
body.nameofyourclass.page-parent            {/* rules for "Projects" */}
body.nameofyourclass.page-parent.page-child {/* rules for "Project 1" */}
body.nameofyourclass.page-child             {/* rules for "Project 1 Subpage 1" */}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: No, not necessarily! To be precise, this is even what I suggest to avoid this way. Just open your `header.php` and search for the body tag. I guess you will find `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`. Replace that with `<body <?php body_class('nameofyourclass'); ?>>`, so you only have to add the css of my last code block to your stylesheet and you're done.

Comment: But keep in mind, that it's not a good idea to handle things like this by applaying a class to the whole site. It's way cleaner to design a template (e. g. project.php, which may even be empty) and only add body_class() when this template gets detected on post. This would mean `<body <?php if(is_page_template('project.php')) body_class('nameofyourclass'); ?>>
` (still talking bout header.php to insert this)

Comment: @CircuitCircus Please keep comment explosion under control by filing [edit]s to your question/answer instead of adding a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved my problem:

In my functions.php I added this:

```
function custom_css_style () {
    global $post;
    $parent = get_page($post->post_parent);
    $grandparent = $parent->post_parent;

    if ( is_page('40') || $post->post_parent == '40' || $grandparent == '40' ) {
        $cssclass = "roadkill-main-content";
    } else {
        $cssclass = "";
    }
    return $cssclass;
}
```

And in my page.php I called this function:

```
<div id="main-content" class="main-content <?php echo custom_css_style(); ?>">
```

So I am able to define the backgroundcolor for cases I handle in my functions.php like this:

```
.roadkill-main-content {
     background-color: #9C006B;
}
```

I tried to make thos work using slugs, but it seems using the ID's is the only way to do it